# XSLT Informal Time Translation

Tags: datetime, xslt-2.0

I'm currently working on a translation of documents for importing as XML to another system, and this involves the translation of a quite informal representation of time, such as the following:

```
<estimated-time>15 mins<estimated-time>
```

And I need to translate this to something like the following:

```
<tr:estimated_time>00:15:00</tr:estimated_time>
```

I've messed around with tokenizing, substrings, and the various time functions and haven't been able to come up with anything, though I am quite inexperienced in XSLT.

Following Jirka's answer, I tried the following:

```
<xsl:template match="estimated-time">
    <tr:estimated_time>
        <xsl:value-of select="time:parseTime(./text(), 'hours')"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="time:parseTime(./text(), 'mins')"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="time:parseTime(./text(), 'seconds')"/>
    </tr:estimated_time>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="time:parseTime">
    <xsl:param name="testedString"/>
    <xsl:param name="lookingFor"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize($testedString, ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="out">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$tokens[. = $lookingFor]">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="index-of($tokens, $lookingFor)-1"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[$pos]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>00</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="if (string-length($out)=1) then concat('0', $out) else $out"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Which always resulted in:

```
<tr:estimated_time>00:00:00</tr:estimated_time>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Update: it works! There were some weird newlines all over the original that I hadn't spotted, which were preventing it from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be there is a more sofisticated or cleaner solution but using tokenizing it should be done for example in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:tst="test">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <times>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="times/time" />         
        </times>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="time">
        <time>
            <xsl:value-of select="tst:getSomething(.,'hours')" />
            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tst:getSomething(.,'mins')" />
            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tst:getSomething(.,'sec')" />
        </time>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="tst:getSomething">
        <xsl:param name="testedString" />
        <xsl:param name="lookingFor" />

        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize($testedString, ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name="tmp">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$tokens[. = $lookingFor]">
                    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="index-of($tokens, $lookingFor) - 1" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[$pos]" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>00</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="if (string-length($tmp) = 1) then concat('0', $tmp) else $tmp" />
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<times>
    <time>05:30:00</time>
    <time>00:05:00</time>
</times>
```

Comment: Well, name getSomething is not actually suitable name for function :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out when I can and update here with how it goes.

Comment: So it doesn't seem to be working for me, which is odd, since it makes complete sense. I'll update the question with a specific example straight from the source file, along with my implementation of your solution.

Comment: This is really strange. I tried your input xml with your xslt and it works :-S

Comment: Couldn't be there any troubles in your input xml? I mean some typos like 'min' instead of 'mins', uppercase/lowercase etc.? Just for sure you can also change `<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize($testedString, ' ')" />` to `<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(normalize-space($testedString), ' ')" />`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks man, my bad. Additionally, if you have time, I've noticed that a fair few of them are instead in the format "15mins", where spaces have been missed out. How would you suggest altering the above to accomodate for that?